# How do I format an SQL where clause parameter in python with single quotes?

Tags: python, sql-server, where-clause, pyodbc

My Python code uses pyodbc to connect to a database and then asks the user for input which I would like to format the 'where' clause in an SQL statement but the where clause requires single quotation marks on my user input to function.

Every time I have tried to format the input to include single quotation mark it doesn't seem work and returns back no rows.

Here is what I am trying to achieve

```
"select FirstName, LastName from person.person where FirstName = 'Kim'"
```

where 'Kim' should be the user input.

here in my code section.

```
user_first_name = print(input("Enter the first name you are looking 
for: "))

cursor.execute("select FirstName, LastName from person.person where 
FirstName = ?", (user_first_name))
```

how do I format the input (user_first_name) so that the parameter has the single quotes in the query field.

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-3NLISNE\SQLNEW;DATABASE=TestDB;UID=python;PWD=password')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

user_first_name = print(input("Enter the first name you are looking for:"))

query = "select FirstName, LastName from person.person where FirstName = ?"
result = cursor.execute(query, (user_first_name,))

rows = result.fetchall()

print (rows)
```

Comment: Remove the `print()` call in the line where you ask the user for their input. You are storing the result of the `print()` call in your variable, rather than the actual user input.

Comment: @Arun - Bad advice. They are already using a proper parameterized query.

Comment: Hi @thesilkworm, thank you so much for your advice. I have mistakenly printed the input which was causing the issue. Once I removed that, then the code worked flawlessly.